# Error while using Jinja2 in html template : [UnicodeDecodeError]

Tags: python, html, flask, ascii, jinja2

So i have an html template with some basic jinja expression in it like :
`{{ post.content }}`
The encoding of my html and python files are utf-8.
So this jinja expression is loading a simple json that i created in a python file called db just like this :

```
post = [{"content" : "Rémi"}]
```

as an example..
The problem is that when rendering the html template with `post.content=db.post`, i get this error :

The weird thing is that i didn't get this error before a few days ago.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/routes.py", line 55, in feed
    return render_template('feed.html', posts=db.posts)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 135, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 117, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/feed.html", line 56, in top-level template code
    <p  id="content">{{ post.content }}</p>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I think the problem is the encoding of the json, but i'm still a beginner and don't know how to change it...
I would appreciate some help :)

Comment: Have you made any changes to your computer's Python setup (for example upgrade the Python version or change it)?   Also can you add this code before you render the template and add the output to the question: `import locale,sys;print(sys.version_info, locale.getlocale())`

Comment: Not as i know... BTW i get this : ```(sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0), (None, None))```                                                          The current version of Python the code is running on is 2.7.10, gonna try with Python 3 to se if there's any difference.

Comment: Okay, well it works fine with python3, lol thanks anyways...

Comment: Hmm, that's telling you that the python2.7 interpreter is running the code, but the traceback shows Python3 packages being used.  So maybe you got your Pythons mixed up :-)

Comment: Yeah, i got some issues while installing python 3 on my mac, a real mess now lol... But with python 3 interpreter it works :)